# Call .bat file within another .bat with parameters

Tags: batch-file, ftp, cmd, 7zip

I need to upload zip files to an FTP server.

My first file looks like this:

```
sqlcmd -S .\SQLEXPRESS -U <user> -P <pass> -i c:\sql_script.sql
7za a -tzip %~dp0\Archive\Backup_daily_full.zip *.bak -v100m
```

For uploading a single file I created this:

```
@echo off
echo user {user}> ftpcmd.dat
echo {pass}>> ftpcmd.dat
echo put %1>> ftpcmd.dat
echo quit>> ftpcmd.dat
ftp -n -s:ftpcmd.dat  {server}
```

I don't know how many .zip files I will have after the backup and how to upload all of them on FTP (how to call that file within main .bat) OR how to simply upload them all at once.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can loop over all the .zip files in the folder, and run the ftp script for each of them.

```
@echo off
for /r %~dp0\Archive %%a in (*.zip) do (
echo user {user}> ftpcmd.dat
echo {pass}>> ftpcmd.dat
echo put %%a>> ftpcmd.dat
echo quit>> ftpcmd.dat
ftp -n -s:ftpcmd.dat  {server}
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a third line to your first file:

```
cmd /c <your-ftp-script>.bat <zip-file-name>
```

As for traversing through a list of zip files, do as the manual says (cmd /?):

> FOR /R [[drive:]path] %variable IN (set) DO command [command-parameters]
>
> Walks the directory tree rooted at [drive:]path, executing the FOR
>       statement in each directory of the tree.  If no directory
>       specification is specified after /R then the current directory is
>       assumed.  If set is just a single period (.) character then it
>       will just enumerate the directory tree.

So store your zipped backup files at a clean location, then use `for /r` to go through the list, calling your second bat file in a loop.